# CSS Animated Menu Buttons + Container?

Tags: css

Alright this may sound like a complete noob question but I was wondering.

Is it possible to use CSS to do what I am requesting?
The link and code listed below, Makes it to where your menu buttons light up when you hover over them, How ever I am wondering if It's possible to do the same effect with a container full of content..

http://71012.site90.net/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{ background:#000; margin:0px; }
div#menubar1{ padding: 24px; border:#999 1px dashed; }
div#menubar1 > a{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:17px;
background: #333;
padding: 12px 24px;
color:#999;
margin-right: 10px;
text-decoration:none;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
-ms-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
-o-transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
}
div#menubar1 > a:hover{
background: #6F8A00;
color:#FFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menubar1">
  <a href="#">Example</a><a href="#">Example</a><a href="#">Example</a><a     href="#">Example</a><a href="#">Example</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Once again, Sorry if this is a complete noob question, I am just really interested because I enjoy the way this effect looks.

Comment: You'd apply the `:hover` to the container and use the child selector (`>` or ` ` depending on what you're wanting) and then the child you want to affect. Ex: `body:hover > div { color:white; }`

Comment: First off, you should test this yourself (: Secondly it would just apply the last color value that can be interpretted that was listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a container to be hovered as opposed to a sibling, you can use the children selectors (`>`, `*`, & ) and apply the `:hover` to the parent

If you're looking to affect the following siblings you can use the sibling selectors (`+` & `~`) and apply the :hover to the sibling that is before the others

The last option is to do as Chris suggested and apply the same hover event to all elements of the class or type, but this only affects elements of the same class of type

For more information and insight for CSS selectors, [**this is a GREAT article**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a class for the effect, and then assign that class to whichever object you would like:

```
.hover-effect:hover {
    background: blue;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="hover-effect">Hover</a>
<div class="hover-effect">Same hover effect applied here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This is exactly what I was looking for, I just didnt completely know if it was possible as I haven't seen it before. Thank you very much once again not only for the content, But the fast reply.

Comment: That's not a container setup... Useful (so keep it) but you should add one that involves a container

Comment: A `div` is a container element. I answered the question based on my guess at the experience level; I interpreted it as, "how do I apply the same style to more than one element"